# why my first WCF Server doesn't work (wrong value returned to client)

Tags: c#, wcf

This is my first WCF Server:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace Myns.MBClient
{

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IManagementConsole
    {
        [OperationContract]
        ConsoleData GetData(int strategyId);
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    public class ConsoleData
    {
        private int currentIndicator;

        [OperationContract]
        public double GetCurrentIndicator()
        {
            return currentIndicator;
        }

        public void SetCurrentIndicator(int currentIndicator)
        {
            this.currentIndicator = currentIndicator;
        }
    }

    class ManagementConsole : IManagementConsole
    {
        public ConsoleData GetData(int strategyId)
        {
            ConsoleData data = new ConsoleData();
            data.SetCurrentIndicator(33);
            return data;
        }
    }

}
```

In client I just call `pipeProxy.GetData(0).GetCurrentIndicator()`

Why program prints `0` while it supposed to print `33`?

Client code (which I think has no problems):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using Commons;
using myns.MBClient;

namespace myns.MBClientConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ChannelFactory<IManagementConsole> pipeFactory =
                new ChannelFactory<IManagementConsole>(
                    new NetNamedPipeBinding(),
                    new EndpointAddress(
                        "net.pipe://localhost/PipeMBClientManagementConsole"));

            IManagementConsole pipeProxy =
              pipeFactory.CreateChannel();

            while (true)
            {
                string str = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("pipe: " +
                  pipeProxy.GetData(0).GetCurrentIndicator());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot serialize around your service contracts - WCF is a **message passing** system - it does **not do remote procedure calls**, e.g. you cannot have one service method return a service class instance - that won't work.

Comment: The program above doesn't "print" anything. Let's see the client.

Comment: how to do what i want to do then?

Comment: you cannot do what you want to do - you need to learn about the capabilities and architect your solution accordingly. WCF is **NOT** a remote procedure call system - you'll never be able to do what you're trying to do. WCF passes messages between systems - those are XML based and thus can **only** contain serialized data - no behavior

Comment: well i need to pass the data. but data should be obtained/calculated on runtime. it doesn't make sense to pass static data, static data might be hardcoded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create your own complex type to use with WCF you have to add a DataContract attribute instead of a ServiceContract, and you should use fields/properties that are decorated with DataMember. And do yourself a favor and use plain DTOs (DataTransferObjects - Objects with only fields/properties but no behavior):

```
[DataContract]
public class ConsoleData
{
    [DataMember]
    public int CurrentIndicator {get;set;}
}
```

You can find more on this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx)

Comment: Exactly - **fields** and **data** **ONLY** - no behavior.